# Merge and sort multiple XML Files with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting, merge

The problem is to merge and sort multiple XML files with XSL and output valid HTML, viewable with Firefox >=3.5 and if possible IE >=7. The answer should be as simple as possible (performance is not important).

File a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <tag>cc</tag>
    <tag>aa</tag>
</root>
```

File b.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <tag>xx</tag>
    <tag>bb</tag>
</root>
```

File index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="merge.xslt"?>
<list>
    <entry>a.xml</entry>
    <entry>b.xml</entry>
</list>
```

File merge.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ph="http://ananas.org/2003/tips/photo">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="list">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <xsl:for-each select="document(.)/root/tag">
            <!-- This will only sort the values of a single file -->
            <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending" />
            - <xsl:value-of select="."/> <br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output:

- aa
- cc
- bb
- xx

Expected output:

- aa
- bb
- cc
- xx

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, very short and easy solution that doesn't have the complexities of any of the other answers: no extension functions, no variables, no `xsl:for-each` ...

Comment: Also added extensive explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The solution to this is a very short and easy transformation** (absolutely *no* extension functions are required!):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <html>
   <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates
       select="document(entry)/*/tag">
      <xsl:sort/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
   </ul>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tag">
  <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided *index.xml* file**:

```
<list>
    <entry>a.xml</entry>
    <entry>b.xml</entry>
</list>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <ul>
      <li>aa</li>
      <li>bb</li>
      <li>cc</li>
      <li>xx</li>
   </ul>
</html>
```

**and it is displayed in any browser as**:

- aa
- bb
- cc
- xx

**Explanation**: **This solution uses the power of the standard XSLT function [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document).** As defined in the W3C XSLT 1.0 Recommendation:

> When the document function has exactly one argument and the argument
>   is a node-set, then the result is the union, for each node in the
>   argument node-set, of the result of calling the document function with
>   the first argument being the string-value of the node

**This explains the effect of this fragment from our code**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates
   select="document(entry)/*/tag">
  <xsl:sort/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

What happens here is that the argument to the `document()` function is the node-set of all `entry` children of the top element of `index.xml`. The result is the union of all document nodes.

**Therefore**:

```
select="document(entry)/*/tag"
```

selects all `tag` elements in all documents referenced in `index.xml`. Then they are sorted (by `xsl:sort`) and each of the element of the already sorted nodelist is processed by the template matching `tag`.

Comment: Accepted, because answer works and is easy to understand. Very good explanation!

Comment: I don't know why I complicated so much. I need some rest. +1 for best and easy approach.